# Heroku logs error is Mongoose error uri parameter to openURI() must be a string and it is a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, mongoose

I am trying to deploy my work on heroku and after solving some errors, one error is not getting fixed and i tried so many methods but all are failing

added : `useNewUrlParser: true,useCreateIndex: true, app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))`

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport')
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const hostname='localhost';
var port=  process.env.PORT || 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const route=require('./routes/api/Routes');



 // DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI

 // Connect to mongo
 mongoose
    .connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true,useCreateIndex: true, })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))


  app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
  app.use(cors())

  app.get('/test', (req,res) => res.send(`<h1>Deployed on Heroku</h1>`))
```

and the error in git bash is

```
State changed from starting to crashed
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:434
 throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' 
 +
 MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got 
 "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or 
 `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

on https://teamse7.herokuapp.com/test shows application error

Comment: What is the return of require('./config/keys').mongoURI ?

Comment: @FrV  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') 
    module.exports = require('./keys_prod')
else 
    module.exports = require('./keys_dev')

Comment: module.exports = {
    mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
}                                                                                                                                   @FrV this is keys_prod

Comment: module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb+srv://******:*******@******.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
}                                                                                                                            @Frv this is keys_dev

Comment: Ok, try console.log(db), if is not a string, that's why it fails

Comment: @FrV mongodb+srv://**********@***********.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
Sever up and running on localhost:8080
Connected to MongoDB                                                                                     prints this string

Comment: Are you sure the uri you pass is correct ?

Comment: @FrV yes it works locally

Comment: Sorry, with the error given I don't see what is going wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the connection to
        `mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://*********@********.mongodb.net/test? 
         retryWrites=true', {useNewUrlParser: true});
         mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
         console.log('Conection has been made!');
             }).on('error', function(error){
          console.log('Error is: ', error);
           });`

Answer (score 4):

That’s why it is important to add to package.json your node version by adding this line:
`"engines": { "node": "your-version" }`
Too, you should declare your other environment variables with Heroku dashboard (that’s the easiest way), under the “settings” tab, then Config Var.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

i had faced same issue in my case it was because of environment variable i was setting it up locally but i didn't knew that we have to set them in heroku as well.
check out this article for more info  [heroku official blog on config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Comment: I love you, I nearly broke my keyboard just now. Thank you so much.